# Base Out State Probabilities by Batting Order Position

Tags: baseball, statistics, sabermetrics

I am looking for the number of PA's (Plate Appearances) that occurred in each of the 24 possible base-out states *split by batting order position*. I am interested especially in the years 2010-2015 in MLB. [Baseball Reference](https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/split.cgi?t=b&lg=MLB&year=2010#all_bases) provides plate appearances by [batting order position](https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/split.cgi?t=b&lg=MLB&year=2010#all_lineu), and by base-out state, but not the two combined. Is there anywhere online where this data can be obtained? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic; or rather, it's specifically *off topic* by the [help] but we're somewhat discussing changing that.  But either way, it seems overly specific... it's possible [opendata.se] would be a better fit for this question.  I am *fairly* confident the answer is that you'd have to pull the information yourself; it's not actually hard to do that, particularly for the period in question (given it's so short).  You can easily pull the PBP data for all 6 seasons from BR and just classify each PA separately.

Comment: You can check out my github repo, https://github.com/snoopy369/Sports.SE , which has some examples of how to do something akin to this - none of them browse PbP pages but the concept isn't substantially more complex (just more pages).

Answer (score -1):

This post has out state by lineup spot but not base-out state:
https://fantasy.fangraphs.com/runs-and-batting-order/

This one has PA with men on by lineup spot:
https://www.twinkietown.com/2020/5/29/21271449/twinkietown-analytics-fundamentals-come-learn-baseball-with-john-sabermetrics-rbis-misleading-stat

That should get you closer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/24754)